# Do creatures occupy cubic space, or are larger creatures still one square tall?

Tags: dnd-4e, 3d-space

Does a large creature need to squeeze to fit into at 5' tall passageway?

Comment: Similar to this question, but not quite the same:  [How much vertical space do a rider and mount occupy together?](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/3707)

Comment: Same rules as [Do tall creatures have to duck elevated obstacles?](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/3658)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From page 200 of the Essentials Rules Compendium:

> **Space:**  A creature's space is the area, measured in squares, that the creature occupies on the battle grid.  This area represents the three-dimensional space that the creature needs to take part in an encounter, allowing it to turn around, attack, fall prone, and so on.  Despite the cubic shape of its space, a creature is not actually a cube (unless it's a gelatinous cube).

So, to answer your question in short:  Yes.

Large creatures require two squares in all dimensions for normal combat.  Therefore, to fit into an area that is only one square high, they would need to squeeze.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that they are filling cubic space for the most part.  A longer creature might not be as tall as the creature is long.

If the tunnel was wide enough, though it seems like the monster could crawl.

Comment: By rules or by common sense?

Comment: Common sense, the rules seem really vague about height.  Also the official miniatures are clearly taller than smaller ones.

Comment: The important thing to remember about the cubic size is that it represents the space that the monster controls (and needs available for effective combat). Just as you can fit many humans into a five by five square on the ground, so too can a long monster have a combat space requirement greater than its actual height.

Answer (score 1):

I would rule that large creatures usually occupy cubic space.  Not only does it make more sense it also makes tactical combat more interesting in situations where height matters.

Answer (score 0):

I know that in previous editions, and specifically 3 and 3.5, that they did occupy cube space.  And I believe that they specifically call that out in the PhB.  Being at work right now, I am unable to look it up however.

I have always ruled that they do occupy cubic space, personally.  Since Giants at 5 feet tall would be ... silly.  :)

Answer (score 0):

When you look at most creatures, the really large ones are usually big in area (3 squares or more) but not tall mathematically.  Gravity has a funny affect on tall things, they tend to be unstable.

I apply the same logic to my game Creatures.  Creatures up to medium in size can fit under a 5' height easily.  No squeeze based on height.  For each size category over medium I assume 2.5' of height on top of 5' for a creature when they are in a standing, relaxed, posture position.

So a 4sq x 4sq creature would be 5' + 10' high, 15' high.  This seems to fit most creatures almost to a tee.  Sometimes I have to over ride this rule, but in general it works really well.

So i would rule that a large creature would have to squeeze, unless their description lead me to think there were short.